# how to return Error from Service layer to ViewModel using PassthroughSubject Error handling

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm, error-handling, combine

I am new to Combine Framework, and facing issue while returning error from Service Layer to ViewModel layer.

Attaching sample code here for reference:

**ViewModel**

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user: User?
    
    func sendUserRequest() {
        @Injected var userService: UserServiceContract
        
        let publisher = userService.get()
        
        publisher.sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] completion in
            if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                self?.error = error
            }
        }, receiveValue: { user in
            self.user = user
        })
        .store(in: cancelBag)
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
protocol UserServiceContract {
    func get() -> AnyPublisher<User, Error>
}

class UserService: UserServiceContract {
    private var cancelBag = CancelBag()
    private let subject = PassthroughSubject<User, Error>()
    
    private var requestHoldBackTimeInterval: TimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }
    
    func get() -> AnyPublisher<User, Error> {
        let repo:AnyPublisher<User, Error> = UserWebRepository().get()
        
        repo.ensureTimeSpan(requestHoldBackTimeInterval)
            .mapError({ (error) -> Error in
                return error
            })
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: { _ in },
                receiveValue: {
                    print($0)
                    self.subject.send($0)
                }
            )
            .store(in: cancelBag)
        return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

In Service layer:

a. I am able to pass response to ViewModel from Service when result is successful - using passthroughSubject.

**b. I am stuck when result is Error: how to handle it in Service layer and later pass that error to ViewModel?**

I am making network call using Combine framework and need help in service layer.

```
View <> ViewModel <> **Service** <> Repository
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.assign(to: &$user)` instead of `.sink` and `.store`.

The pipeline is usually created in the `ObservableObject`'s `init`.